# Titanium.UI.Label property height

Tags: android-emulator, titanium

In my code I am doing this:

```
var taskLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({color:'#777', top:3, textAlign:'center', height:'auto', text:task.title});
Ti.API.info('Next info is: taskLabel.height');
Ti.API.info(taskLabel.height);
```

But, the output from this is:

```
[INFO] [123,883] Next info is: taskLabel.height
```

And nothing more, it looks like it breaks silently, but I guess it shouldn't, based on [the API](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Label-object.html).

I am trying to sum some heights of the elements, but I would prefer it behaved like html `postion:relative`. Anyway, I'd like to read the height in float, how can I achieve that?

Comment: is it working with a fix height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a fixed width when you use an auto height. For example:

```
var taskLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({color:'#777', top:3, textAlign:'center', height:'auto', width: 200, text:task.title});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not going to get the height until it is actually rendered and added to view or window.

Answer (score 0):

You cant read the height property off like that, if you didn't manually define it.

It has to be added to a view, and then displayed (assuming it doesn't auto display) before Titanium will return anything about the height.

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var taskLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({color:'#777', top:3, textAlign:'center', height:'auto', text:task.title});
window.add(taskLabel);
window.open();
Ti.API.info('Next info is: taskLabel.height');
Ti.API.info(taskLabel.height);
```

That should work to show the height.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 var lbl_obj = Ti.UI.createLabel( { height: 'auto', text:'Test Label', top:10 } );
 var height = lbl_obj.toImage().height;
 Ti.API.info(height);
```